# DjangoRestFramework loop issues, it only runs for the first element

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

It is supposed to run 3 times, but it only runs for the first element. I have tried to run it on python console and the same approach works fine. I am not able to figure out the issue with the code.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveVisitView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        visits = json.loads(request.POST.get('request'))
        for i in range(len(visits['visits'])):
            serializer = VisVisitsSerializer(data=visits['visits'][i])

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

## model

```
class VisVisits(models.Model):    
    visit_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
    app_local_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    school_program = models.ForeignKey(SchProgramForSchools, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UsrUsers, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vis_visits'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.visit_id)
```

## data

```
{
 "user": "1",
 "visits": [
    {
      "action": "i",
      "local_id": "170",
      "visit_id": "",
      "school_program_id": "1",
    },

    {
      "action": "i",
      "local_id": "172",
      "visit_id": "",
      "school_program_id": "1",
    },

    {
      "action": "i",
      "local_id": "172",
      "visit_id": "",
      "school_program_id": "1",
    },

  ]
}
```

Comment: You use `return` in the loop. Put it out from for loop. And use `enumerate` rather than `range`. :)

Comment: Can you please add your models, also is there any relation between visit and user?

Comment: @ruddra added the model (few important fields). `user` is a ForeignKey in VisVisits model class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about to use `many=True` attribute with serializer? 
It can dealing with multiple objects.

Look [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) too.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveVisitView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        visits = json.loads(request.POST.get('request'))
        serializer = VisVisitsSerializer(data=visits['visits'], many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: `Many = True` did not work. That also inserts only the first row (with no error). not sure if this is because the 2nd element in json for visits has validation issue. but even in that case I would want to return those issues like it does for the 1st element in json. but when I keep `return`(the last one) out of loop then it goes to the 2nd element but it stops there because the 2nd element has an issue(validation). What I am trying to achieve here is that I want to insert all the visits and if some of them has an validation issue then return those validations with local id at end of the loop.

Comment: @RajuSingh Please attach your VisVisitsSerializer, too. If there're no error, your serializer may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Yuda for reply. I want to return errors. Kind of achieved that by defining `visits_issues = []` before loop starts and then append error into it by code `visits_issues.append({'local_id':visits['visits'][i]['local_id'], 'validation_issues': serializer.errors})` in the else for  `if serializer.is_valid():`. but now I am struggling to get `user` for each visits. `user` will always be the same for each visits. I tried to store `user` with `visits['visits'][0].update({'user':visits['user']})` (written it before loop starts) but it only gives user for the first element

Comment: @RajuSingh - can you get user from `request.user`?

Comment: it comes with same json arrary `visits = json.loads(request.POST.get('request'))`